# substr() to preg_replace() matches php

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, substr

I have two functions in PHP, `trimmer($string,$number)` and `toUrl($string)`. I want to trim the urls extracted with `toUrl()`, to 20 characters for example. from `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HU3GZTNIZ6M` to `https://www.youtube.com/wa...`

```php
function trimmer($string,$number) {
    $string = substr ($string, 0, $number);
    return $string."...";
}

function toUrl($string) {
    $regex="/[^\W ]+[^\s]+[.]+[^\" ]+[^\W ]+/i";
    $string= preg_replace($regex, "<a href='\\0'>".trimmer("\\0",20)."</a>",$string);
    return $string;    
}
```

But the problem is that the value of the match return `\\0` not a variable like `$url` which could be easily trimmed with the function `trimmer()`.

The Question is how do I apply `substr()` to `\\0` something like this `substr("\\0",0,20)`?

Comment: No idea what your question is.

Comment: Thanks you. It was added.

Comment: You want to look at `preg_replace_callback()`. With `preg_replace()` that won't work as you might already found out.

Comment: thanks you, but older php versions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/manual/it/function.preg-replace-callback.php):

```
function _toUrl_callback($m) {
  return "<a href=\"" . $m[0] . "\">" . trimmer($m[0], 20)  ."</a>";
}
function toUrl($string) {
  $regex = "/[^\W ]+[^\s]+[.]+[^\" ]+[^\W ]+/i";
  $string = preg_replace_callback($regex, "_toUrl_callback", $string);
  return $string;
}
```

Also note that (side notes wrt your question):

1. You have a syntax error, '$regex' is not going to work (they don't replace var names in single-quoted strings)
2. You may want to look for better regexps to match URLs, you'll find plenty of them with a quick search
3. You may want to run through htmlspecialchars() your matches (mainly problems with "&", but that depends how you escape the rest of the string.

**EDIT**: Made it more PHP 4 friendly, requested by the asker.

Comment: It looks like you are definitely right. but I am working with php 4.0.x, just return this error  ` syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION`

Comment: PHP 4 is REALLY obsolete, but it should work, I'm editing my answer to make it more PHP 4 friendly

Comment: @Max PHP 4 is 16 years old! You really want to upgrade your PHP version.

Comment: I am sorry checking my server, I am using PHP5, and it works.